# Is there a way to use the Java Stream API to filter values that occur a certain number of times?

Tags: java, java-stream

Right now, I am using 4 loops to cycle through a 2D array and find the number of times each value occurs. Then, I check to see if the number of occurrences is greater than a limit, e.g. 10. If it is, I add it to an ArrayList of filtered values. This is highly inefficient, though, and the Stream API seems to have some methods that could do this, I just don't know how.

```
ArrayList<String> filteredValues = new ArrayList<String>();

//data is a String[][]
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
        int occurences = 0;

        for(int k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
            for(int l = 0; l < data[0].length; l++) {
                if(data[i][j].equals(data[k][l])){
                    occurences++;
                }
            }
        }

        if(occurences >= 10) {
            filteredValues.add(data[i][j]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How is data declared? String[][] data?

Comment: Yes, it is a `String[][]`.

Comment: Did you look at [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-)? Group, then filter the groups with high enough count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more efficient way of checking iteratively:

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<data[i].length; j++) {
        String val = data[i][j];
        counts.put(val, counts.getOrDefault(val, 0) + 1);
    }
}

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: counts.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() >= 10) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

It only iterates through the values once.

Here is a way of doing it using the streaming API:

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = Stream.of(data).flatMap(Stream::of)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v->1, (x, y)->x+y));

List<String> overThreshold = counts.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(v->v.getValue() >= 10)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make an array list of data, then group/count:

```
//This creates a map of text to a list with all its values:
Map<String, List<String>> listMap = Arrays.asList(data).stream()
            .flatMap(array -> Arrays.asList(array).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s));

//The following filters filters out all keys mapped to lists of size lower than 10
List<String> occuringAtLeast10Times = listMap.keySet().stream()
            .filter(key -> listMap.get(key).size() >= 10)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You should call `Map#entrySet()` rather than `Map#keySet()` to avoid the overhead of looking up the value in the `Map` during the subsequent filter step. Also it's not necessary to collect the values into a list since the lists are then thrown away.